# Android: Marker on StreetViewPanoramaView

Tags: android, google-maps, google-street-view

I show on my Android App a map with stores on its location with the posibility to see the street view.

I want to show the store's exact location in the street view, so, **Is there a way to add a marker on StreetViewPanoramaView?**

I know that it is possible on Web with [Overlays within Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays) but I don't find anything for Android.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible on [Web](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays) and [IOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/streetview#zoom). However, its not available for Android platform. This is more likely a feature request.

I found this blog which shows how to display StreetViewPanoramaView with markers. You can use this as a work around: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/11/display-streetviewpanoramaview-in.html